Running arm64v8 docker container on x86 : apt update fails
I run docker from a WSL2 (under Windows 10).
Here is my minimalist Dockerfile :
FROM arm64v8/ubuntu
CMD ["bash"]

I build it like that : sudo docker build -t test_4 .
Then I run it with : docker run -ti test_4
I am now in bash within the container :
#uname -a gives :
... aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
So I assume I'm well on a aarch64 platform.
But then # apt update gives :
Ign:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/noble/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/noble-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/noble-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/noble-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

And of course, no apt install is possible...
By the way, if I try any other image from arm64v8 (such as busybox, gcc, python), I get the same error :
Unable to find image 'arm64v8/busybox:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from arm64v8/busybox
docker: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries.

Any idea ?
Thanx in advance !
